# Finding the height of a balloon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

> A balloon moves up vertically such that if a stone is thrown from it with horizontal velocity $u$ relative to it, the stone always hits the ground at a fixed point $ 2u^2/g$ horizontally away from it. If the height of the balloon as a function of time $t$ is expressed as $h=(2u^2[1-e^{-gt/xu}]/g$, then find the value of x.

My only question is is that $e$ (euler number) a misprint or I don't know something..
$
 Answer$ $is$ $x=2$

Comment: Why should $e$ be a misprint? The function $e^{-x}$ is omnipresent in physics - and not only physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $e^Y$ is almost certainly not a misprint. This function ([the exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)) is omnipresent in mathematics of functions, physics, and any discipline of sciences or social sciences that use mathematics. It is an extremely important function – basically the most important operation after addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

The exponential function $e^Y$ is a power and $e$ is the most natural base for powers. All other powers may be written as $x^y = e^{y\ln x}$. So a function of one parameter $e^Y$ and its inverse $\ln x$ are enough to write down all powers $x^y$, among other things. $C\cdot e^x$ are the only functions whose derivative is the same as the original function, and so on.

So you were probably missing something and it may change now. The exercise just gives some particular height $h(t)$ of the balloons as a function of time that involves the exponential – such fucntions are the simplest functions in mathematics after the ratios of polynomials.

Comment: What can I be missing I wonder if there is a way somehow bring up e in velocity of balloon and by the way answer is x=2.

Comment: I am not sure whether you understand the English language of that exercise. The function including $e^Y$ was an *assumption* of the problem you were given, a part of the question. You're not supposed to derive the question, you're supposed to derive the answer. Clearly, one can't do that if she doesn't know what $e^Y$ means, but if that's so, it doesn't mean that the problem is defective in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical speed is
$$v=\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{2u}{x}e^{-gt/ux}$$

and the acceleration reads
$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{g}{xu}\frac{2u}{x}e^{-gt/ux}=-\frac{g}{xu}v.$$

This would be a particle going upwards under action of an effective force
$$F=ma=-\frac{mg}{xu}v.$$

This is drag type force. Since there is neither a term corresponding to the weight nor a term corresponding to the buoyancy force we can assume they cancel out each other. So the balloon was simply thrown upwards with an initial speed $2u/x$, since $v(t\rightarrow 0)=2u/x$, and the drag exponentially vanishes this speed, $v(t\rightarrow\infty)=0$. Everything seems to be alright.